# Undefined offset?? 1 after die statement echoing $_POST

Tags: php, arrays, post

I am trying to upload a file through the POST array, with the 'newFile' name from the input tag being the index in the $_POST array that contains the name of the file I am uploading.  I also have a dropdown list with a different name value of 'existingFile'.  When I throw a die statement on my destination location, using print_r to look at the POST array, I find that it is missing the newFile index, still has the default value of the existingFile index, and has a random '1' displaying after the rest of the array is finished with the print_r function.

```
<form data-ajax="false" id="formFileSubmit" method="post" action="echo.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <!-- Restrict file uploads that will fail -->
                    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000" />
                    <!-- Name of input element for upload determines name in the $_FILES array -->
                    <input id="fileSelect" type="file" name="newFile" onChange="checkIfFile()" />
                    <select id="loadFile" data-role="button" type="file" name="existingFile" data-native-menu="false" onChange="previousFile()">
                        <!-- Add dropdown items for every file in the uploads directory, based on Title csv file metadata -->
                        <option name="loadList" id="defaultLoad" value="default" selected="selected">Choose a previously saved file...</option>
                        <?php
                        //Generate options for selection list based on previously saved files
                           $dir = 'uploads';
                           $files = scandir($dir, 1);
                           $j = 0;
                           foreach($files as $fileName/* File in directory */){
                                if($files[$j] == 'about_uploads_folder.txt.txt' || $files[$j] == '.' || $files[$j] == '..'){
                                    //Don't add a load option
                                }else{
                                    echo "<option name='load' value='".$fileName."'>".$fileName."</options>";
                                    echo '<br />';
                                }
                                $j++;

                           }
                        ?>
```

What is this undefined offset error, and how do I get the 'newFile' index to show up?

Comment: What's the `$j` for? You could just use `$fileName` in the loop.

Comment: use `$fileName` instead `$files[$j]` inside the loop

Comment: Nevermind, I found a bunch of stuff i need to change.  Sorry for wasting your time